# Need Remove newline characters onchange event of inputted text Javascript

Tags: javascript

### I want to remove new line characters like \r\n,\t,\n and other special characters

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<input type="text" id="ctext" onchange="myFunction();"/>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("ctext").value.toString();
  var result = str.replace("\n", "");
  result = result.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'').replace(/__/g,'').replace(/\\/g, "");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
  document.getElementById("ctext").value = result;
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Actually, When we input text in text box and onchange event occur then i want to remove new line characters e.g. from '\n' to '', '\r\n' to '', '\t' to ''. but unfortunately it gives output as n from '\n', rn from '\r\n'. I mean it removes only backward slash not the full newline characters.

I want string getting from input text to be escaped from special characters, new line characters like '\n', '\r\n', '\t' etc. i.e. if we input this string "sdfjn\nkl454\r\n\t__._" from the input text box. then onchange it should be like sdfjnkl454. but it is showing sdfjnnk454rnt.

Comment: When you type "\n" into a text box, that isn't going to transform into a newline character. It will literally be the string backslash-N, the code equivalent of which would be `\\n`.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because in javascript `\` is an escape character, hence `"\n` is the same as `"n"`.

You could try this regex to replace those:

```js
const string = `I have whitespaces and new line chars
that are
replaced. Same with  tabs`
const replacedString = string.replace(/[\n\s\r\t]*/g, "")
console.log(replacedString);
```

Comment: Right your are.. But he can also achieve his desired output by adding some lines.

Answer (score 1):

The line `var result = str.replace("\n", "");` in your code replaces only the first occurrence of `\n`.

In order to remove all the occurrences of `\n`, `\r` and `\t` use regex in the first parameter of `replace` method like below:

`var result = str.replace(/\n|\r|\t/g, "");`

The above statement states that if you find any `\n` or `\r` or `\t` then simply replace it with "".

Also, in case you need to remove all the underscores as well then you can simply update the above statement to:

`var result = str.replace(/\n|\r|\t|_/g, "");`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `str.replace(/\\n|\\r|\\t/g, "")` if you want to replace "\n","\r","\t"

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("ctext").value.toString();
  var result =  str.replace(/\\n|\\r|\\t/g, "");
  result = result.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'').replace(/__/g,'').replace(/\\/g, "");
  result = result.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
  document.getElementById("ctext").value = result;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<input type="text" id="ctext" onchange="myFunction();"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for getting exact output you wanted.
Try it

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<input type="text" id="ctext" onchange="myFunction();"/>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("ctext").value.replace('\\n','\n');
   str = str.replace('\\s','\s');

  str = str.replace('\\r','\r');

  str = str.replace('\\t','\t');

 var result = str.replace(/[_.\n\s\r\t__]*/g, "");

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
  document.getElementById("ctext").value = result;
  return false;
}
</script>
```